# Found between a vertical pump discharge head casing flange and pump base metal melted like weld build-up with evident overheating . Please assist

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Found between a vertical pump discharge head casing bottom flange and pump base metal melted like weld build-up with evident overheating. Could such a defect be caused by arc welding nearby?

Comment: please add a picture to your post